# Xcode Preview Fail on VirtualBox

Tags: xcode, swiftui, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox to work with Xcode, everything was smooth till I tried to compile and run my base file swift code. It compiled successfully but I am unable to see the preview as i get error:
failed to launch preview shell:
The request to open "com.apple.dt.XcodePreviews" failed.
com.apple.dtxcodepreviews.service (0).
The code of a file where preview is should be launched:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View{
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix it, and if not can I somehow run previews on my Iphone device?

I tried deleting DerivedData folder, clean project but I have no idea what else could be a solution.
Versions: Xcode 12.4
MacOS Ventura 13.3